# Multiple Return In java

Tags: java

In a method, we can pass the multiple parameters, but there is only one return.

```
public r1 method(p1, p2, p3,....) {

}
```

New feature?

```
public ClassA, ClassB, ClassC method(p1, p2, p3,....) {
    if(cod-1) {
        return ClassA
    }
    if(cod-2) {
        return ClassB
    }
    if(cod-3) {
        return ClassC
    }

}
```

Now, we are solving it by creating extra DTO class to wrap these results. Some return value may be optional.

```
class Extra{
    private ClassA;
    private ClassB;
    private ClassC;
}

public Extra method(p1, p2, p3,....) {
    if(cod-1) {
        return new Extra().setClassA()
    }
    if(cod-2) {
        return new Extra().setClassB()
    }
    if(cod-3) {
        return new Extra().setClassC()
    }   
}
```

**Update**   Sometime I need like

```
ClassA, ClassB, ClassB = method1(p1, p2, p3);

if(r1) {
}

if(r1) {
}

if(r1) {
}
```

**Question** Is there way without creating new DTO?

If I use List or collection, the caller function will be busy.

Comment: And you question is?  You have few choices, the one you've used, arrays, `List` or `Map`...

Comment: What would be your recommended syntax for receiving multiple return values from a method?

Comment: No, there is no mechanism today (and no proposed mechanism) to add "multiple" returns to Java.

Comment: _If I use List or collection, the caller function will be busy._ Busy with what?

Comment: if you are very sure that you are going to have only 3 elements, i suggest you to use arrays rather than collections

Comment: This "guess what has been returned" looks like a "code smell" to me. In a development environment where reliable SW is the target this would be quickly banned by coding rules.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct but actually return is a statement which will not only return the value but also transfer the control to the next expression after the function call so what will be the benefit of using multiple return values. Instead we can use List or Map as suggested by @MadProgrammer.